# Почему на mdx revo сайте новости на главной странице выводятся с датой 01 Января 1970 года 03:00?

Tags: modx, revo

Добрый день, подскажите, почему на главной странице сайта [http://романов2016.рф/#news](http://%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B22016.%D1%80%D1%84/#news) новости выводятся с такой датой? Хотя как тут [http://романов2016.рф/news/](http://%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B22016.%D1%80%D1%84/news/) все нормально? Вывожу через

```
 [[!getResources?
    &includeContent=`1`
    &tpl=`MainNews`
    &includeTVs=`1`
    &processTVs=`1`
    &parents=`3`
    &limit=`3`
    &hideContainers=`1`]]
```

Дата в чанке MainNews 
`[[*publishedon:dateRU]]`

снипет dateRU

```
<?php
$month_arr = array('01' => 'Января',
               '02' => 'Февраля',
               '03' => 'Марта',
               '04' => 'Апреля',
               '05' => 'Мая',
               '06' => 'Июня',
               '07' => 'Июля',
               '08' => 'Августа',
               '09' => 'Сентября',
               '10' => 'Октября',
               '11' => 'Ноября',
               '12' => 'Декабря'
              );

$time = strtotime($input);
$month = strftime('%m', $time);
$day = strftime('%d', $time);
$year = strftime('%Y', $time);
$hour = strftime('%R', $time);

return "$day $month_arr[$month] $year года $hour";
```

Пробовал выводить дату без этого снипета, просто через

```
  [[*publishedon:strtotime:date=`%a %b %e, %Y`]]
```

Выводит тоже самое

Comment: Потому что функция strtotime() не смогла распознать строку из $input как время и все ваши остальные телодвижения дальше по коду не имеют смысла. Что вы даете на вход в переменной $input? Что пишет сервер в своем логе ошибок?

Comment: Установил чистый modx создал снипет dateRU больше я ничего не делал

Comment: Так дело в том, что я и без этого снипета когда вызываю дату, ситуация не меняется

Comment: Если выводить через [[*createdon:dateRU]] то все работает, с чем это связанно?

Comment: Я не в курсе, что там делает и как modx в своем коде. Я вас спросил `Что вы даете на вход в переменной $input? Что пишет сервер в своем логе ошибок?` По второму вопросу вы ни чего не ответили - откройте лог ошибок сервера и посмотрите, что он там в конце настрочил. По первому, чтобы ответить поставьте перед строкой `$time = strtotime($input);` вывод $input так `var_dump($input);`.

Comment: Стало быть `[[*publishedon]]` не заполнен и возвращает `0` и соответственно ваш сниппет в работе с `0` возвращает `1970...`. А в `createdon` значение заносится автоматом при создании документа.

Comment: В логах ошибок нету, var_dump($input); возвращает string(1) "0"

Comment: На других страницах сайта то все нормально

Comment: @ВячеславЯшников, ищите выше по коду, почему у вас сюда передается строка `0`, а не строка со временем.

Comment: `[[+publishedon:dateRU]]` попробуйте в чанке. Не `[[*` а `[[+`

Comment: Чанком работает, сможете объяснить, почему так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конструкцией `[[*publishedon:dateRU]]` в чанке `MainNews` Вы обращаетесь к дате публикации ресурса в котором происходит вызов `getResources`

Чтобы обратиться к `publishedon` обрабатываемых ресурсов сниппетом `getResources` нужно использовать конструкцию вида [плейсхолдер](https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/tag-syntax), который записывается, как `[[+name]]`

В итоге, должно быть:

`[[+publishedon:dateRU]]`